# On solution methods for min-min optimization problems

Tags: reference-request, nonlinear-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization, smooth-functions

Closely related (although not equivalent) to minimax optimization problems is the following:

$$\min_{x \in \Omega} \min_{i=1,...,q} f_i (x).$$ Here, $\Omega \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $f_i: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is continuously differentiable. I am looking for references on algorithms for this kind of problems. Specifically, I am interested in steepest- descent -like methods. Can you suggest a good reference/survey?

Comment: You can just minimize each function separately and then choose the smallest one.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the comment. That is a good idea. However, you are assuming that I have a global optimization solver, which is not the case. I am looking for an algorithm that converges to a Clarke stationary point.